# How i **2 different from i * i in python while calculating?

Tags: python

I was trying to solve [Leetcode#279.Perfect-Squares](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/)

When I tried `i ** 2` in loops, I got Time Limit Exceed. But once I change it to `i * i`, the code was accepted, that means `i * i` is faster than `i ** 2` in python

**What principles in python3 caused this difference?**

*Code and result for reference:*

Use `j * j`, AC, beats 23%

```
class Solution:
    def numSquares(self, n: int):
        if n < 2:
            return n
        dp = [n] * (n + 1)
        dp[0] = 0
        dp[1] = 1
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            j = 1
            while j * j <= i:
                dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - j * j] + 1)
                j += 1
        return dp[-1]
```

If change all `j * j` to `j ** 2`, TLE.

Comment: The source is out there, but a generalized form of exponentiation, one that doesn't only work with positive integers, will be more complex than a simple multiplication.